# SHOW ALL BUTTON can show in report preview MS ACCESS

Tags: ms-access

I'm not very expert in using this Microsoft access, I just try my best and try to follow the tutorial on youtube. I'm stuck with showing all records in the preview report. for now when I select the place that I want, the preview report just showing the selected places. But when I click the show all button and I click the preview report, it still comes out with selected places, not all records. Any changes that I need to change at the 'show all' button?

```
Private Sub cmdshowall_Click() 
Dim showall As String 
showall = "SELECT * FROM Register" 
Me.RecordSource = showall 
Me.Requery
Eng Sub
```

Comment: Show the code you use to display the "selected places", to make sure you're running Requery against the same object.

Comment: Check the Filter and FilterOnLoad properties of report. Any criteria saved in Filter?

Comment: selected places I use is a combo box. and at the preview report button, I add at Where Condition = [PKRC]=[Forms]![Search by Date]![PKRC]

Comment: so now  what I want is when I click preview report besides i can choose selected places using combo box, the preview report can view all records when i click show all button

Comment: this is combo box coding that i use for selected places 'Private Sub cboSearchPkrc_AfterUpdate()

Dim SearchPkrc As String

SearchPkrc = "SELECT * FROM Register  WHERE PKRC = '" & Me.cboSearchPkrc & "'"
Me.RecordSource = SearchPkrc
Me.Requery



End Sub'